# How to put background color on dynamically created TR element

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, tr

I used the Bootstrap date-time picker and now I need to put a background color to an element inside bootstrap calendar.

I have created this HTML:

```
<tr HERE I NEED STYLE>
    <td>
        <span class="timepicker-hour" data-time-component="hours" title="Pick Hour" data-action="showHours">01</span>
    </td>
    <td class="separator">:</td>
    <td>
        <span class="timepicker-minute" data-time-component="minutes" title="Pick Minute" data-action="showMinutes">30</span>
    </td>
    <td>
        <button class="btn btn-primary disabled" data-action="togglePeriod" tabindex="-1" title="Toggle Period">PM</button>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Is there easy way to put background on first TR element with css?

Comment: if the elements are dynamic and you need to style them you need to add a class to the TR or select them with :nth-child (or the similar) in css (as scoopzilla points out in their answer). If you're the one generating these rows that becomes trivial. If you're not generating these rows it is just the slightest bit harder.

Answer (score 1):

Hope it works!!
Use inline style

```
<tr style="background-color:blue;"><td><span class="timepicker-hour" data-time-component="hours" title="Pick Hour" data-action="showHours">01</span></td><td class="separator">:</td><td><span class="timepicker-minute" data-time-component="minutes" title="Pick Minute" data-action="showMinutes">30</span></td><td><button class="btn btn-primary disabled" data-action="togglePeriod" tabindex="-1" title="Toggle Period">PM</button></td></tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using jQuery:

```
$("#id_of_tr").css('background-color', 'red');
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a global `<style>` for the table.

Put your styles for that `<tr>` in there.

```
<style type="text/css">
    tr {
      background-color: #ff0000;
    }
</style>
```

You could even get tricky and add it only to every other:

```
<style type="text/css">
    tr:nth-child(even){
      background: #ff0000
    }
</style>
```

Just run this style right before your dynamic loop.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure, but this may help you.

```js
$('tr.some_class:first').css("background-color", "blue");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr class="some_class">
    <td><span class="timepicker-hour" data-time-component="hours" title="Pick Hour" data-action="showHours">01</span>
    </td>
    <td class="separator">:</td>
    <td><span class="timepicker-minute" data-time-component="minutes" title="Pick Minute" data-action="showMinutes">30</span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <button class="btn btn-primary disabled" data-action="togglePeriod" tabindex="-1" title="Toggle Period">PM</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="some_class">
    <td><span class="timepicker-hour" data-time-component="hours" title="Pick Hour" data-action="showHours">01</span>
    </td>
    <td class="separator">:</td>
    <td><span class="timepicker-minute" data-time-component="minutes" title="Pick Minute" data-action="showMinutes">30</span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <button class="btn btn-primary disabled" data-action="togglePeriod" tabindex="-1" title="Toggle Period">PM</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="some_class">
    <td><span class="timepicker-hour" data-time-component="hours" title="Pick Hour" data-action="showHours">01</span>
    </td>
    <td class="separator">:</td>
    <td><span class="timepicker-minute" data-time-component="minutes" title="Pick Minute" data-action="showMinutes">30</span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <button class="btn btn-primary disabled" data-action="togglePeriod" tabindex="-1" title="Toggle Period">PM</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

You can also generate random colors using `Math.random()`

> var back = ["#ff0000","blue","gray"];
>
> var rand = back[Math.floor(Math.random() * back.length)];
>
> $('tr.some_class:first').css("background-color", rand);